# How to suppress X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN response header?

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options, response-headers

I am trying to remove `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` header or set it to `ALLOWALL`.

I have set it in my `web.config` and the same in my IIS's Http Response Headers for the site, yet still I am getting `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` in my browser and iframe content does not render.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOWALL" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It's the same in Firefox and Chrome.

Is there anywhere else I should look for it or can modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs and add this line

```cs
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

Be aware though that this means anyone can use your application in an iframe. So it'll be worth adding a new file with this code:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class NoIframeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following line to RegisterGlobalFilters method in FilterConfig.cs:

```cs
filters.Add(new NoIframeAttribute());
```

Now it is safely back into your application, you can remove the xframeoptions wherever you need to in your application with

```cs
Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```