# SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true not removing x-frame-origin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a .net MVC app running on 4.6.1 I am trying to make a page work in an iFrame. I read the best way to do this is to update SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader in Global.asax. So I did that:

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

But I cannot for the life of me get rid of the X-Frame-Origin header. I do not have any x-frame-origin settings set in web.config.

I am following instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434599/how-to-suppress-x-frame-options-sameorigin-response-header) to turn off the header on application_start, then add it back as a global filter, then remove it on a page by page basis. But I can't even get the first step to work where I remove the header from the entire application.

Is there anywhere else this could be set I am overlooking?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach could be to use the fact that all modern browsers (that excludes IE11) will ignore X-Frame-Options if Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive is set.

You can set the header "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' <host(s) of sites to allow>;"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem: The Firewall application installed on my server was injecting the X-Frame-Origin header on every request, so it was overriding what had been set in the application. All is working as expected now.